Looking for a movie about a weird fog invading a coast town
I saw this movie some years ago, and I'm guessing it is from the 1980 to 2000's. It is in English, color, and features a male and female leads, and I think the woman's child. The movie happens in the modern days of its release, so around the 90's.
What little I can recall about the plot is that it all happens in a coast town. There is a lighthouse, which the characters eventually go into at some point. A supernatural white fog is periodically invading the town, or parts of it, and I remember that eventually our main characters need to outrun this fog in a vehicle. It all happens in an american town, with a Sheriff, and mostly during the night. Characters move all over town, the lighthouse, some house, etc. I seem to remember some sort of parade in the movie, as well? And maybe some weather station.
I've searched for terms such as "killer fog", and eliminated The Fog, as well as its modern remake. Other search results that I have excluded are Storm of the Century, The Mist, House of Sand and Fog, Fogbound, and Darkness Falls.

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/30271/horror-movie-about-fog

That sounds exactly like The Fog, that you ruled out?  Are you sure? See this detailed synopsis:  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080749/synopsis?ref_=ttpl_pl_syn  What eliminated The Fog for you, if so?

@TurboPT I checked the trailer, but it didn't ring any bells, neither with the actors or with attacks on the fog or with the ghosts (?). If no successful answers come up here, I'll have to rent it and make sure it is neither of the Fogs, though.

Is it John Carpenter's Village of the Damned(1995) ? It is a remake of 1960's movie with the same name.


It is in English, color, and features a male and female leads, and I think the woman's child.`

Yes. The movie is in English and colour. There are male and female leads in the movie. Yes, both the leads have children. Male lead's child(Mara) is the leader of the children and female's child is the one(David) of the characters who survives at the end of the movie.
The movie is set in a quiet coastal town in Northern California.  A weird(yes, supernatural) fog invades this coastal town which causes a blackout for some hours. All the creatures in the town fall unconscious. 
From the Wikipedia page of the film:

The quiet coastal town of Midwich in California's Marin County is invaded by an unseen force(fog), causing a blackout for six hours, which leaves ten women mysteriously pregnant. Nine months later, the babies are born simultaneously on one night, though one is stillborn. At first, they all appear to be normal, but it does not take the parents long to realize that they aren't. The children are shown to all have pale skin, white hair, fierce intellect, and cobalt eyes. However, they also do not appear to possess a conscience or personalities. The children display eerie psychic abilities that can result in violent and deadly consequences whenever they experience pain or provocation.

There is a house in front of the shore which is shown many time in the movie. We can see a construction like a light house in the film. It is visible in the poster too. This is the house of the lead role.This might be the house you are talking about. There is a sherrif character too which was portrayed by Squire Fridell. Yes, The climax of the movie and some important movies happen in the night time.

An angry mob gathers to kill the children, but the leader is set on fire and burns to death while the state police sent there are instead hypnotized into shooting each other in a chaotic gun battle.

This angry mob gathers to kill the children with torches in their hands. They move like a parade. So, there is a parade too. This clip is shown in the trailer of the film too. But I don't know about a weather station.
Look at the trailer of the movie. It has many cars moving and travelling.

Apart from taking place in a quiet coastal town, this doesn't seem to line up with what the OP is describing at all.

@Steve-O I don't think so. Fog, coastal town, timeline, Sherrif, parade, male and female lead, their children, a house(probably a light house too), scenes at night, patrolling at night in cars. I find these matches from the description of the OP.

Darkness Falls?

In the Nineteenth Century, in Darkness Falls, Matilda Dixon is a good woman, who exchanges with children their baby teeth per coins. One day, her face is burnt in a fire in her house, she becomes sensitive to light and uses a china mask to protect her face against light. When two children are not found in the town, Matilda is blamed by the population and burnt in a fire, as if she were a witch. She claims to be not guilty and curses the whole population of the town and their descendants, stating that when each child loses the last tooth, she would come to get it, and if the child looks at her, she would kill him or her. After her death, the two children are found, and the shamed citizens decide to bury this sad and unfair event and never mention it again. Twelve years ago, the boy Kyle accidentally saw the Tooth Fairy, and she killed his mother. All the persons in Darkness Falls but his girlfriend Caitlin accused the boy of murdering his mother and sent him to an institution, considered deranged. In the present days, Caitlin calls Kyle to help her young brother Michael, who has seen the Fairy Tooth and is afraid of the dark. 

The movies stars a male and female lead (Emma Caulfield and Chaney Kley), also  a child (Lee Cormie). The only difference is the child is Emma Caulfied's character's brother, not son.
The town definitely has a local lighthouse (where the climax takes place) so it must be costal. 
Now the monster in the movie isn't a fog, but the tooth fairy. However, she can only kill in the darkness, so it's mainly shown as darkness chasing people, rather than a monster (I mention this, because your memory could be replacing darkness with a fog?)
Another difference is the lack of sheriff. There is a police captain though. Plus the movie was released in 2003...
However, during the movie, a lightning storm blacks out the town, so there are scenes that take place all around the town. There is also a car chase, attempting to outrun the darkness, as they head from a hospital to the lighthouse. 
Also with the darkness being the main villain here, it takes place at night.

Despite being a good call, I distinctly remember the white fog chasing things around, so this cannot be it.
